# How to smooth a jagged mesh boundary after cropping/deleting a part from the mesh?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edit-mode

Here is a part of a cropped mesh viewed from the top, which is being used as basis for a height-map.

[image: Mesh]

Is it possible smooth the boundary curve so an extrusion downwards would not cause FreeStyle to generate lines for every 90 deg turn in the column?

[image: Column]

Comment: can u pls show or tell us, how you created your blocks?

Comment: @Chris: Create mesh. The used `Displace` modifier

Comment: Finding this question's answer would be very useful since jagged edges after deleting some part of a mesh are a big problem. To be honest, I've never found a solution for this myself.

Comment: You could alt-double-click select boundary edges (before extrusion) and from the ctrl-V vertex menu, > Smooth them. (Or similar via modifiers) I'm not sure that would fix your Freestyle problem, though. Can you describe / illustrate which features you want Freestyle to pick up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it this way:

1. Select the boundary (using `Select by trait`/`Non-manifold`)
2. Choose `Edge`/`Mark freestyle edge`
3. Extrude
4. Select all new faces
5. Use the `Smooth` edit tool, locking Z axis (thus only x and y values are changed)

Result:

[image: Result]

This will keep the exact shape of the original mesh. Another option is to use `Decimate`, with a suitable factor. This will not preserve the original mesh but may be sufficiently close.

Answer (score 2):

How about using *Subdivision Surface* modifier?

[image]